# Looping through functions containing callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am trying to use NodeJS 6.3.1 repeat a similar async function to access paged data. The aim is to calculate the number of pages of data based on the total rows and the rows per page then call the API to retrieve each page of data using the **request** package.

For example if there were 34 rows in total with 10 records per page I would need to call each of the following URLs.

```
www.example.com?page=1
www.example.com?page=2
www.example.com?page=3
www.example.com?page=4
```

Given each of these calls requires a callback, how can I iterate through them?

Comment: Promises are cool for that

Comment: I was trying to implement `promise.all()` but could find no decent examples. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `Promise.all()`:

```js
// This is will be your get request function
function getRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(url);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

var promises = [];
var url = 'www.example.com?page=';

for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  // Creating a list of promises (get requests)
  promises.push(getRequest(url + i));
}

// After all of the promises have resolved, all of the responses will be
// concatinated into a list of responses and passed in like this:
Promise.all(promises).then(function(allResponses) {
  console.log(allResponses);
});
```

UPDATE

If you are using the default node request the `getRequest()` method will look something like this:

```
var request = require('request');

function getRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        resolve(body); // or resolve(response) if that is what you are looking for
      } 
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This would be a more useful answer if you showed how to promisify the actual `request()` function rather than just showing a dummy promise function.

Comment: @jfriend00 Like that.. You will just need to change the `setTimeout` to the http get method and you pass in `resolve` as the callback function. Besides, if you don't provide a callback, there is a good change that the request method will return a promise any way

Comment: The request package that the OP is presumably referring to is probably this https://www.npmjs.com/package/request and doesn't return a promise.

Comment: I am also not sure what HTTP API to use, there is more then one out there.

Comment: Using that one that you mentioned, instead of the `setTimeout(...)` replace it with `request(url, resolve)`

Comment: Don't tell me.  Edit your answer to improve it.  I'm trying to help you improve your answer.  You also have to show how to handle errors and you can't just pass resolve as the callback.